# Azure DevOps: How's the deployment group job status decided?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I have a deployment group job with setting in below pic as 33%. How's the status of job determined to be "failed" or partially succeeded"? The description of the setting only specifies "It is also used to determine the success and failure conditions during deployment" which is not really clarifying.

[image]

In first attempt, status is failed even though only 4 machines didn't succeed

[image]

After couple of attempts, status is "partially succeeded" even though 23 failed

[image]

Comment: Does my explanation and the thread link could help solve your puzzle now? If yes, you can accept it as answer which could help other SO users who has the same puzzle with you refer to whether it is works. If still has puzzle, feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7333#issuecomment-394154666) in Merlin's answer below : "Deployment group phase will be “partially succeeded” if deployment is attempted to all the targets, event the deployment is failed in any of the target."

Couldn't locate this piece of info anywhere in the official docs.

Comment: This because, as normal, we did not document the pipeline status definitions. What you see this  sentence is from our pipeline team engineer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have been know that this does not has any relevant with the number of the failed deployment.

In fact, this only relevant with one option: **Continue on error**

[image]

When you enable this option in the task, even one step failed, it will still continue the deploying. At last, it will display **partially succeeded**.

Instead, if you did not check this **Continue on error** option, even it only has one failed step, the status will still display **failed**.

To verify this, you can check your task configuration which exists in `Control Options`.

Also, you can check this thread: [VSTS Release - Phase with partially succeeded](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7333#issuecomment-394154666).

> Deployment group phase will be “partially succeeded” if deployment is
>   attempted to all the targets, event the deployment is failed in any of
>   the target.